# "surplus fat" VS "surplus of fat"

Tags: grammar

Consider this sentence :"Obesity is a surplus fat deposited in the adipose tissues"   I am wondering if " surplus fat" is correct or "surplus of fat" . "surplus" can be noun as well as adj so I think both styles are correct. Am I in a right track ?

Comment: Almost correct IMHO, *"Obesity is **a** surplus **of** fat ..."*  or *"Obesity is surplus fat ..."* or even *"*"Obesity is surplus fat **that gets** deposited..."*

Comment: Get rid of the _a_: the usage here is uncountable. _surplus fat deposited_.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=excess+fat%2C+surplus+fat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexcess%20fat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurplus%20fat%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cexcess%20fat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurplus%20fat%3B%2Cc0) shows that "excess fat" is used a lot more commonly in this context, but "surplus fat" weighs in also.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and contribution..

Answer (score 1):

As stated above I think either "a surplus of fat" or "surplus fat" (no "a") is fine, grammatically.

However, I'm not sure it's correct, medically. Obesity is a property of the person, it is not the fat itself. Obesity is not the fat, it's the person with the fat. So, although this may be more verbose, I might say, "A person suffering with obesity has a surplus of fat stored in adipose tissue." Or something - but, I'm not a doctor.

Comment: Thank you for this very through analysis  :-) . Now it becomes clear for me .. the first phrase " surplus of fat" is a noun phrase and bcz we have an "a" before it should be a noun or a noun phrase . without an "a", we should use an adjective or an adjective phrase " surplus fat" not " surplus of fat" which forms a noun phrase..